# Building Go project from Dockerfile says package not in GOROOT

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

This is the Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM golang:1.13 AS go-build-env

FROM utilities:debug

# Build go binary
RUN apk add gcc go
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64
COPY myApp/* myApp/
RUN cd myApp && go build && mv ./myApp ../

CMD bash
```

I am getting the following error when it is doing `go build`:

```
 > [stage-1 5/8] RUN cd myApp && go build && mv ./myApp ../:                                              
#12 0.751 found packages main (main.go) and codec (zwrapper.go) in /myApp
#12 0.751 main.go:17:2: package codec is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/codec)
```

My GoApp structure is:

```
myApp
├── codec
│   └── zwrapper.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── vendor
    ├── codec
    │   └── zwrapper.go
    ├── github.com
    ...
```

When I run `go build` from `myApp` directory manually it works, but when building the Dockerfile, it keeps complaining. Do I have to setup a GOPATH and GOROOT in the Dockerfile? Any ideas for how to get around this?

Comment: Each `FROM` line starts over with a new base image, so you're using whatever version of Go is getting installed by `apk add`; the `FROM golang:1.13` line has no effect.  Would it make more sense to do the compile in the first stage with a known version of the toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

Go has a system variable set location for the build location (which is strict). This is either your home directory +`go/src/` or the GOPATH.

In your case you have to set your GOPATH:

```
ENV GOPATH /myApp
```